# Как узнать на момент старта приложения, запущен на кластере или standalone-сервере?

Tags: java, spring, websphere

Приложение на spring развернутое на was с базой oracle.
Приложение разворачивается на разных серверах (кластер с нодами или стенделон)
Есть необходимость на момент старта приложения, в одном из бинов знать точно, где я стартую и использовать соответствующий конфиг.

Первый вариант это вынести настройку на сам сервер was записав в переменную строку
Для этого на сервере создал переменную myVar

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
само создание переменной

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Cоздал в web.xml такую связку

```
 <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>myVar</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>java.lang.String</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
    </resource-ref>
```

А так же пытаюсь вычитать в коде вот так

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
String myVar = (String) ctx.lookup( "cell/persistent/myVar" );
```

Но приложение перестало стартовать

Пробовал другой вариант, указывать свойства на сервере
`Servers->ServerTypes->webSphere application server` 
и чтение через System.getProperty - мне не подходит, так как у меня много нод и создавать на всех эту переменную - проблематично..

Что можно еще попробовать или изменить в предложенном варианте?

Answer (score 0):

А вот и ответ: добавить в настройки кластера was Environment->Naming->Name space bindings свой переменную, например вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в файлe webapp\WEB-INF\imp-web-bnd.xml

```
 <resource-ref name="env/myVar" binding-name="env/myVar"/>
```

в файле webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>env/myVar</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>java.lang.String</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

В java коде вот так

```
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    String myVar = (String) ctx.lookup( "env/myVar" );
```